# How can I open more than one window in OneNote for Mac

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-onenote-2016

One of the most requested features of OneNote for Mac is that of opening more than one window.  E.g. I would like to have one page open on the left side, and another page on the right, or wherever.  Unfortunately, Microsoft doesn't support this feature yet.

See [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_onenote-onenote_mac/multiple-onenote-for-mac-windows/562cba9e-e741-43e9-8c67-a12303b4a89c?auth=1) and [here](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/327165-onenote-for-mac/suggestions/6158369-mac-allow-multiple-onenote-windows-to-be-open-sim)

How can I open and see multiple windows in OneNote for Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine that by now, all of you mac users have see that [you can have multiple One Note windows](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-onenote/id784801555?mt=12) open on your Mac.  Thanks folks at Microsoft!  I love it!

Comment: This should be the top answer now. Maybe you could point out that Window->New Window is the way to actually do this.

Comment: You can also use the **CTRL** + **M** keyboard shortcut to open a new window on a Mac too now.

Answer (score 2):

After moving to a mac 2 months ago, I tried out OneNote for Mac recently and became frustrated several times when I couldn't open multiple windows and saw that I wasn't missing something, the app was missing something.

Then today, I realized that if I ctrl-clicked a page and selected 'Copy link to page', then I could paste that link into my browser and open up the one note in the browser.  Then I could have the browser in a window, and one note in another one.

[image: Copy Link to page]

Comment: note, you can now simply open a new window instead of using a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a page in new window by `right click > open in new window`

[image: open in new window]